# Unable to remove related data when checkbox unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have two sets of checkboxes. When first div's checkbox checked, it will fetch data via ajax call and fill in second div. When another checkbox is checked, it will append to the second div. But when the first div's checkbox unchecked, the appended checkbox list must be removed. I never thought it would be this hard though! Can someone help me with this please?

First table that fire an ajax call

```
<table class="large-7 large-centered columns"><tr>
              <?php
              $i=0;
              while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
              {
                  $i++;
                  //echo $i;

              ?>
             <td>
             <label for="level_<?php echo $row['catid'];?>">
              <input type="checkbox" class="level" id="level_<?php echo $row['catid'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['catid'];?>">
             <span></span>
              <?php echo $row['catname'];?>

              </label>
             </td>

              <?php
              if($i==2)
                  {
                      echo"</tr><tr>";
                      $i=0;
                  }
              }
              ?>
        </tr></table>
```

secondly, appended list

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-7 large-centered columns" id="show_subjects">
     <table>
<?php
while($row = $statement->fetch())
{
    $levels=$row['catname'];
    $levels_id=$row['catid'];
    $subjects= $row['subname'];
    $subjects_id= $row['subid'];


    if($last_category != $levels) 
       {
        $last_category = $levels;
       ?> 

      <tr><th class="subjects"><?php echo $levels;?>
       <?php 
       }
       ?>
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $subjects;?></td>
     <td>

    <label for="<?php echo $subjects_id;?>">
   <input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="sub[<?php echo $subjects_id;?>]" id="<?php echo $subjects_id;?>" value="">
    <span></span>
    <?php echo  $subjects;?>
    </label>
    </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    <?php
    if($last_category != $levels)
    ?>
    </th></tr>

    <?php
}
?>
 </table>   
</div>
```

script

```
$("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]").on("change",function()
{
    var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     var t=this.id;
     //alert("click " + t);
     var nowshow=t.split("level_").join("");

    fetchSub(nowshow);
     }
      else {
         var me=$("th.subjects");
         var remove_id=this.id;
         //alert($id);
         $("th"+selectedval).remove();//This is where I wish to know how to remove


     }
});
```

HTML as in Inspect element for the second checkbox set

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="subjects">...
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<label for="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="sub[5]" id="5" >
<span></span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Provide HTML markup as rendered by browser

Comment: @A.Wolff, how do I get it pls??

Comment: @sherly In your browser, ctrl+u to get the source or inspect element. At the moment, you have provided server side code which is quite unreadable

Comment: @A.Wolff, provided the html as per source code

Comment: Let's say checkbox `#level_5` is unchecked, so which element should be removed?

Comment: @A.Wolff, the entire table for that id should be removed. table structure updated above

Comment: @A.Wolff, also on emore thing I noticed just now, for the first cehckbox it displays id like level_5 but in second checkbox it displays just 5. MAybe can filter this using split()..But how to remove that table for the id?

Comment: Im' sorry but still unclear what you are expecting. If checkbox #level_5 is unchecked, which specific TABLE should be removed? Your posted HTML markup doesn't have any relevant ID or class for the TABLE so i don't get your logic there

Comment: @A.Wolff, when level_5 is unchecked, table inside <div id="show_subjects"> must be removed.This table structure is posted above.

Comment: `$('#show_subjects').find('table').remove();` would remove it

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes it removes but ,how to remove by ID..Now if I add two cehckbox and uncheck only one it removes the entire table

Comment: `how to remove by ID` I don't understand it. I don't understand all your expected behaviour. I'm quite lost in trying to understand it so i'm sorry, i couldn't help you more